# How to combine two non-adjacent ranges using Union?

Tags: vba, excel, union

I want to create a range (Rng3) that combines the first row and the third row of the table below.

```
1   2   3   4   5
11  22  33  44  55
111 222 333 444 555
```

To do this, I use this script:

```
Sub combineRange()

Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3 As Range

Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1")
Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E3")

Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)

End Sub
```

Now, when I inspect Rng3 I see that only the first row of the data is in this range (1,2,3,4,5) and not the third row of the table.

What am I doing wrong?

If the ranges are adjacent, then it does work!

```
Sub combineRange()

Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3 As Range

Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1")
Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E2")

Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)

End Sub
```

Comment: I imagine the problem is simply in how you are "inspecting" `Rng3`.

Comment: something tells me that Union does not do what you think it should.  What do you think the output range should be?

Comment: I inspect Rng3 using Add watch... in the debug modus. The output should be '1,2,3,4,5 & 111,222,333,444,555'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeeded by defining the range as a collection and by using a function that transforms the collection to an array. See code below:

```
Sub combineRange()

Dim CombinedRange As Collection
Set CombinedRange = New Collection

CombinedRange.Add ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1")
CombinedRange.Add ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E3")

'transfer cominedRange to array using function CollectionToArray
varTable = CollectionToArray(CombinedRange)

End Sub

 Function CollectionToArray(col As Collection) As Variant()
    Dim arr() As Variant, index As Long, it As Variant
    ReDim arr(col.Count - 1) As Variant
    For Each it In col
        arr(index) = it
        index = index + 1
    Next it
    CollectionToArray = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Check again your code. What do you get here?

```
Sub combineRange()

    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range
    
    Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1")
    Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E3")
    
    Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)
    MsgBox Rng3.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Then I get $A$1:$E$1,$A$3:$E$3

Comment: And this is not what you want? @MartenOnnink

Comment: No, I want Rng3 to contain 1,2,3,4,5 & 111,222,333,444,555

Comment: `Rng3` is a range, not an array. To process a discontiguous range you need to loop through its areas. As I mentioned in my comment to your original question, I think it is your inspection that is flawed, not the `Union` operator.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I loop through its areas in order to process discontiguous range?

Comment: @MartenOnnink To iterate over Areas, you need two loops: first iterates over Areas property and second loop - over cells of each area: `For Each rngArea in rngUnion.Areas: For Each cell In rngArea: Next: Next`

Comment: Ok thanks! @JohnyL This code works as it loops trough the cells I need `For Each rngArea In Rng3.Areas
    For Each Cell In rngArea
    
      MsgBox Cell
    
    Next
Next` Sorry, but it is still unclear to me how I use this for loop in order to get the data I need (eg 1,2,3,4,5 & 111,222,333,444,555)

Comment: @MartenOnnink The `cell` variable holds a cell (`Range`).

Answer (score 0):

Note: the line

```
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3 As Range
```

defines `Rng3` as a `Range` and the others as `Variant`. Use:

```
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same data (first row only) using: Dim Rng1 As Variant, Rng2 As Variant, Rng3 As Range

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know when you use `UNION` it combines ranges in columns not rows, you could try transposing your ranges befores using `UNION`:

```
Sub combineRange()

    Dim Rng1,Rng2,Rng3,Rng4 as Range

    Set Rng1 = application.transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1"))
    Set Rng2 = application.transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E3"))

    Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)
        Rng4=application.transpose(Rng3)



End Sub
```

You are right actually I have been triying different alternatives without success,  I think that VBA is doing it right i mean, when you use UNION in non contiguous ranges you indeed get a new range but this is not "kind of matrix anymore" so you cannot iterate throug it with ease and this new range is useless since it is a one column range (VBA Stacks the tow ranges instead of merge them).

Please Check this example and I hope it helps.

```
Sub test()
 Dim R1, R2, R3, R4 As Range


  Set R1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A10")
  Set R2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2:B10")
  Set R3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:C10")
 Set R4 = Application.Union(Application.Index(R3, , 1), Application.Index(R3, , 3))
 Set R5 = Application.Intersect(R4, R4)

 Debug.Print R4.Address
 Debug.Print R4.Rows.Count
 Debug.Print R4.Columns.Count

 For Each mycell In R4
  Debug.Print mycell
 Next
```

[image]

Comment: UNION also works for rows. If the ranges are adjacent, then it does work: `Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1")
Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E2")`The code you provided gives a run-time error(13): Mismatch, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep you are right I have added new information. Hope it helps otherwise use Python / Pandas ( I am moving on to it) ;)